# Tengo un problema con el bucle de este código

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Estoy intentando aprender visual basic pero por más que lo intento el mensaje de introducir sueldo se me repite 3 veces antes de que pase al console.read

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim empleados, x, cont1, cont2 As Integer
    Dim sueldo, gastos As Single
    x = 1
    cont1 = 0
    cont2 = 0
    gastos = 0
    Console.Write("Número de empleados: ")
    empleados = Console.Read()
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Introduce el sueldo del empleado: ")
        sueldo = Console.Read()
        If sueldo >= 1000 And sueldo <= 2500 Then
            cont1 = cont1 + 1
        End If
        If sueldo > 2000 Then
            cont2 = cont2 + 1
        End If
        gastos = gastos + sueldo
        x = x + 1
    Loop While x <= empleados
    Console.WriteLine("Número de empleados con sueldo entre 1000 y 2500: " & cont1)
    Console.WriteLine("Número de empleados con sueldos mayores que 2000: " & cont2)
    Console.WriteLine("Gastos de la empresa en los sueldos: " & gastos)
End Sub
```

Comment: Prueba con `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: Me aparece esta excepción System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Single' is not valid.'

Comment: que numero escribiste en empleados? console read va a leer un solo caracter.. si vos escribis 34 empleados va a leer 3, luego en el siguiente read 4 y luego en el siguiente un enter.... o sea.. no hace lo que vos queres que haga...

Answer (score 2):

**Lo que sucede:**

Al utilizar `Console.Read()` esta función retorna el siguiente carácter (correspondiente al valor entero en formato ASCII) en el buffer del stream de entrada que en tu caso serán siempre el valor que ingreses en "Número de empleados" + el valor correspondiente a la tecla "enter".

Por esta razón es que se repite el texto "Introduce el sueldo..." varias veces porque el stream de entrada tiene algunos valores pendiente para ser consumidos.

Recuerda que `Console.Read()` retorna el código ASCII correspondiente a la primera tecla ingresada. Por tal razón tu código no funciona de forma adecuada ya que al ingresar por ejemplo el valor "2" lo que se almacena es el valor "50" que es el código correspondiente al número "2" en ASCII.

Tabla ASCII: https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/

**La solución:**

Como siempre hay miles de forma de llegar a la meta, te planteo la mía.

Puedes usar `Console.ReadLine()` para obtener el texto ingresado, pero este (al igual que otras formas) tienen el problema de que el usuario puede ingresar texto que no sean valores enteros que es lo que el código espera (y por eso pueden ocurrir errores como el que mencionas en un comentario).

Para esto podemos intentar convertir el valor ingresado en entero para que si el texto que el usuario ingreso es valido el código siga funcionando.

Esto lo hacemos con la función `Integer.TryParse` que intenta convertir un string en entero y si no puede retorna false.

Entonces tu código quedaría algo como:

```
...
If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), empleados) Then
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Introduce el sueldo del empleado: ")
        If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), sueldo) Then
            If sueldo >= 1000 And sueldo <= 2500 Then
                 cont1 = cont1 + 1
            End If
            If sueldo > 2000 Then
                 cont2 = cont2 + 1
            End If
            gastos = gastos + sueldo
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop While x <= empleados
End If
...
```

Referencias:

[Console.Read()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.8)

[Console.ReadLine()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_ReadLine)

[Integer.TryParse()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Me da error en el tryparse de sueldo

Comment: @AlbertoLopez que te dice ?

Comment: Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error BC30519 Error de resolución de sobrecarga porque no se puede llamar a ninguna de las funciones 'TryParse' a las que se tiene acceso sin una conversión de restricción:
    'Public Shared Overloads Function TryParse(s As ReadOnlySpan(Of Char), ByRef result As Integer) As Boolean': El parámetro 'result' correspondiente al argumento se reduce de 'Single' a 'Integer'.
    'Public Shared Overloads Function TryParse(s As String, ByRef result As Integer) As Boolean':

Comment: Intenta con: `Dim sueldo, gastos As Integer` en vez de: `Dim sueldo, gastos As Single`

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado la expresión de función de Console.Read por Console.ReadLine que te lee la línea completa. También he cambiado el tipo de dato Single a Integer.
Tu código funciona bien siempre y cuando lo que introduzcas sean los números enteros.

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim empleados, x, cont1, cont2 As Integer
    Dim gastos, sueldo As Integer
    x = 1
    cont1 = 0
    cont2 = 0
    gastos = 0

    Console.WriteLine("Número de empleados: ")
    empleados = Console.ReadLine()
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Introduce el sueldo del empleado: ")
        sueldo = Console.ReadLine()

        If sueldo >= 1000 And sueldo <= 2500 Then
            cont1 = cont1 + 1
        End If
        If sueldo > 2000 Then
            cont2 = cont2 + 1
        End If
        gastos = gastos + sueldo
        x += 1
    Loop While x <= empleados
    Console.WriteLine("Número de empleados con sueldo entre 1000 y 2500: " & cont1)
    Console.WriteLine("Número de empleados con sueldos mayores que 2000: " & cont2)
    Console.WriteLine("Gastos de la empresa en los sueldos: " & gastos)
    Console.WriteLine("Pulsa enter para continuar...")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```